# How do I get a list of all existing Debian packages of all architectures online?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dpkg, apt-cacher

I need some online service that gives me a list like this command:

`apt-cache pkgnames | sort`

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [packages page at debian.org](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#view). Select the branch (stable / testing / sid) you need, go to a next page, in the bottom there will be a link to all packages page.

E.g. [this](https://packages.debian.org/stable/allpackages) is a page with all packages for debian stable.