# How do I get a list of all existing Debian source packages of all architectures online?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dpkg, apt-cacher

I need some online service that gives me all existing **source** packages in Debian.

A source package is something like this:

https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/wireshark

It contains several binary packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same recipe as given in answer to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/508944/86440) works here too: [the list of “source” sections](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/) in the various suites has an “All source packages” entry which leads to a page listing all the source packages, [as HTML](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/allpackages) or [as compressed text](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/allpackages?format=txt.gz).

Comment: Do you know if there is a single file, where I can offline extract the information which binary packages belong to a certain source package

Answer (score 0):

The [Debian Package Tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/) may help.

If you look up [Wireshark](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/wireshark) for example, you can see this source package creates multiple binary packages such as 
wireshark-common,
wireshark-dev,
wireshark-doc, etc.